# Facing "No commands were issued in the test" when i insert for loop in my test method

Tags: javascript, cypress

```
describe('Verify the schedule', () => {

    it('Schedule Case1', () => {
        let year = '2025'
        cy.get('#openCalendar').click()
        //Year selection
        for (let i = 1; i >= 1; i++) {
            let innerYear
            cy.get('div.yrtext').then(($y) => {
                innerYear = $y.text()
            })
            if (innerYear == year) {
                break;
            } else {
                cy.get('button.nextyear').click({ force: true })
            }           
        }
       
    })
})
```

if i comment out the above **for** loop, launching the site in browser and please refer the screenshot for error

[Issue faced in the cypress test runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fptr4.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming from the `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` plugin, not Cypress.  Please refer to the plugin for specifics on the error you received.

In addition, this test is not properly written.  There are numerous examples in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app), of recommended ways to construct tests.

Comment: I need to click the same element till my expected text appears. Help me on this...How to achieve using for loop?